# How to get the children of specific parent?

Tags: jquery

There are several HTML segments like that. I want to check the "check_item" which belong to    **this** "shopcart-con" class when "check_all" clicked. But when I click the "check_all", all "check_item" was checked. How to fix it? Thanks

HTML:

```
<div class="shopcart-con" data-merchant-id="1">
    <div class="shopcart-list">    
            <div class="shopcart-lstop"><input type="checkbox" class="check_all" name="select"/>fruit shop A</div>
             <div class="shopcart-lscon">
             <ul class="shop_contentul" data-product-id="1">
                 <li class="checkinp"><input type="checkbox" class="check_item" name="aihao" /></li>
                 <li class="checkimg"><img src="images/home10.png" width="100%" height="75px"></li>
                 <li class="checknum" >
                     <p class="lineheight30">apple</p>
                       <span class="shopcart-num">
                        <input type="button" name="" class="inp-reduce">
                        <input type="text"  name="" class="num" value="5">
                        <input type="button" name="" class="inp-add">
                        </span>
                </li>
                    ￥<span class="unit_price">8.00</span> 
                    <p><font color="#808080" size="2px"><s> $12.00</s></font></p>
                    <p>x<label class="shuli">5</label></p>
                    <input class="delbtn" name="">
            </ul>
            <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>
             <div class="shopcart-lscon">
             <ul class="shop_contentul" data-product-id="2">
                 <li class="checkinp"><input type="checkbox" class="check_item" name="aihao" /></li>
                 <li class="checkimg"><img src="images/home10.png" width="100%" height="75px"></li>
                <li class="checknum" >
                    <span class="shopcart-num">
                        <input type="button" name="" class="inp-reduce">
                        <input type="text"  name="" class="num" value="5">
                        <input type="button" name="" class="inp-add">
                        </span>
                </li>
                    ￥<span class="unit_price">8.00</span> 
                    <!-- <p><font color="#808080" size="2px"><s> $12.00</s></font></p> -->
                    <p>x<label class="shuli">5</label></p>
                    <input class="delbtn" name="">
            </ul>  
            <div class="clear"></div>
             </div>
             <div>
              <p class="shopcart-money">共计<label class="product_quantity" data-merchant-id="1">10</label>  sum：$<label class="price_sum" data-merchant-id="1" style="color:red">80</label></p>
             </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.check_all').click(function(){
        var checked_items = $('.check_all').closest('.shopcart-con').find('.check_item')
        console.log(checked_items.length)
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $.each(checked_items, function(i,val){
                val.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
            $.each(checked_items, function(i,val){
                val.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : you are using `$('.check_all').closest` this will find `shopcart-con` under all `check_all`. But you need to find `shopcart-con` for clicked `check_all`, hence use `$(this)` like  `$(this).closest`

```
$('.check_all').click(function(){
        var checked_items = $(this).closest('.shopcart-con').find('.check_item')
        console.log(checked_items.length)
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
            $.each(checked_items, function(i,val){
                val.checked = true;
            });
        }else{
            $.each(checked_items, function(i,val){
                val.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2uw4kdw/1/)**

You can make your code even shorter, you need not to iterate all checkbox and set its property, see below code

```
$('.check_all').click(function(){
        var checked_items = $(this).closest('.shopcart-con').find('.check_item')
        console.log(checked_items.length)
        $(checked_items).prop('checked',this.checked);
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b2uw4kdw/2/)**